# pjax timesout and loses the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, pjax

So I have a page loaded by pjax.

It has a bunch of hyperlinks:
example:

```
<a href ='http://my-site.com/test#abc123'>
```

For some reason if pjax times out, then the url loses the #abc123 part and shows:

```
http://my-site.com/test
```

Is this a known issue or is there a solution for it?